# Move search logic from controller to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Now i do search logic in controller:

```
def index
    @title = "All cars"
    #show manufacturers only with cars
    @manufacturers = Manufacturer.select('*')
    @manufacturers = @manufacturers.where('count_cars > ?', 0)

    @cars = Car.select('*')
    #manufacturer
    @cars = @cars.where('manufacturer_id = ?', params[:filter_manufacturer]) if not params[:filter_manufacturer].blank?
    #model
    @models = Model.select('*')
    @models = @models.where('manufacturer_id = ?', params[:filter_manufacturer]) if not params[:filter_manufacturer].blank? and not params[:filter_model].blank?
    @models = @models.where('count_cars > ?', 0)

    @cars = @cars.where('model_id = ?', params[:filter_model]) if not params[:filter_model].blank?
    #years
    @cars = @cars.where('year >= ?', params[:filter_year_from]) if not params[:filter_year_from].blank?
    @cars = @cars.where('year <= ?', params[:filter_year_to]) if not params[:filter_year_to].blank?
    #district
    @cars = @cars.where('district_id = ?', params[:filter_district]) if not params[:filter_district].blank?
    #body type
    @cars = @cars.where('car_body_type_id = ?', params[:filter_body_type]) if not params[:filter_body_type].blank?
    #fuel
    @cars = @cars.where('car_fuel_id = ?', params[:filter_fuel]) if not params[:filter_fuel].blank?
    #transmission
    @cars = @cars.where('car_transmission_id = ?', params[:filter_transmission]) if not params[:filter_transmission].blank?
    #wheel drive
    @cars = @cars.where('car_drive_wheel_id = ?', params[:filter_drive_wheel]) if not params[:filter_drive_wheel].blank?
    #doors
    @cars = @cars.where('doors = ?', params[:filter_doors]) if not params[:filter_doors].blank?
    #without damage
    @cars = @cars.where('damage = ?', false) if params[:filter_damage]
    #with customs
    @cars = @cars.where('customs = ?', true) if params[:filter_customs]
    #not crashed
    @cars = @cars.where('crash = ?', false) if params[:filter_crash]
    #price
    @cars = @cars.where('price >= ?', params[:filter_price_from]) if not params[:filter_price_from].blank?
    @cars = @cars.where('price <= ?', params[:filter_price_to]) if not params[:filter_price_to].blank?

    @cars = @cars.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
end
```

Do i have to move this logic to model? And if yes, please help me with markup.

Comment: You can write a scope under models, combine all the lines within the one line. Example for your Manufacturer model,

scope manufacturers, lambda{ select("*").where('count_cars > ?', 0) }

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can move this logic to model.

you need to add scope for that

```
@manufacturers = @manufacturers.where('count_cars > ?', 0)
```

that convert into scope like

```
scope :count_car, where("count_cars > ?", 0)
```

then after you can call as

```
 @manufacturers = @manufacturers.count_car
```

same as create others scope for that

or

you can also define a method in your model, for example

```
@cars = @cars.where('manufacturer_id = ?', params[:filter_manufacturer]) if not params[:filter_manufacturer].blank?
```

that convert to

```
def cars(manufacture_id=nil)
  where('manufacturer_id = ?',manufacture_id ) if manufacture_id.present?
end
```

you can call this method same as scope

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
@cars = Car.search(params)
```

In Car Model

```
def self.search(params)
    cars = Car.select('*')
    cars = cars.where('manufacturer_id = ?', params[:filter_manufacturer]) if not params[:filter_manufacturer].blank?
    cars = cars.where('model_id = ?', params[:filter_model]) if not params[:filter_model].blank?
    #years
    cars = cars.where('year >= ?', params[:filter_year_from]) if not params[:filter_year_from].blank?
    cars = cars.where('year <= ?', params[:filter_year_to]) if not params[:filter_year_to].blank?
    #district
    cars = cars.where('district_id = ?', params[:filter_district]) if not params[:filter_district].blank?
    #body type
    cars = cars.where('car_body_type_id = ?', params[:filter_body_type]) if not params[:filter_body_type].blank?
    #fuel
    cars = cars.where('car_fuel_id = ?', params[:filter_fuel]) if not params[:filter_fuel].blank?
    #transmission
    cars = cars.where('car_transmission_id = ?', params[:filter_transmission]) if not params[:filter_transmission].blank?
    #wheel drive
    cars = cars.where('car_drive_wheel_id = ?', params[:filter_drive_wheel]) if not params[:filter_drive_wheel].blank?
    #doors
    cars = cars.where('doors = ?', params[:filter_doors]) if not params[:filter_doors].blank?
    #without damage
    cars = cars.where('damage = ?', false) if params[:filter_damage]
    #with customs
    cars = cars.where('customs = ?', true) if params[:filter_customs]
    #not crashed
    cars = cars.where('crash = ?', false) if params[:filter_crash]
    #price
    cars = cars.where('price >= ?', params[:filter_price_from]) if not params[:filter_price_from].blank?
    cars = cars.where('price <= ?', params[:filter_price_to]) if not params[:filter_price_to].blank?
    cars
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the @cars.where query build up, look into something as Ransack:
https://github.com/ernie/ransack

This Gem allows you to build queries easily depending on the parameter names. See their wiki for some nice examples: https://github.com/ernie/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching